# Rigid body connect settings

Tags: add-on, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm following this tutorial: [Blender3D Tutorial - How To Make Dynamic Rigid Body String](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydX7bzLFbTo) on how to make a dynamic rigid body string and since it's made in 2.79 I'm having some trouble finding the settings shown here, specifically Chain by distance.

[image: screenshot of rigid body tools settings from blender 2.79]

I found the connect setting in Blender 2.8, it's here, but not sure where the other settings are...

[image: blender 2.8 settings]

So the question is, where are the Rigid Body tools settings, specifically the connect body ones! Thanks so much for your help in advance!

Comment: You're talking about "Chain by distance", do you mean you know where it is in 2.7 but not in 2.8? In that cas where is it in 2.7? And what part of the video are you referring to?

Comment: Yes, as visible in the screenshots, in 2.79 it's in the tools shelf, but since 2.8 doesn't have it anymore I can't find that setting anywhere. He changes it at 7:03!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I think it was a bug! I closed the program and opened it up again and got this pop up window!

[image]

Comment: yes,  Object > Rigid Body > Connect, then operator box  ;)